# Cross compile with linux libraries on windows

Tags: gcc

I have some functional libraries (Qt) builded on linux Mint and I already built some test applications (cross compile) for ARM that works. Since it was impossible to cross compile the same libs on Windows, despite all efforts and the excellent cross compiler (Linaro) I wonder if it's possible a second approach.

It's possible to take required so + headers and use them in cross compilation on Windows for the same ARM? (assuming the cross compiler will be the same).

In fact, I can link with linux so libs like regular a's ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: How can u cross-compile in windows with toolchain wh is for linux... you need windows compitable toolchain executables... y u r trying on windows is der any particular reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always build GCC as a cross-compiler by yourself for the desired targeted architecture and platform (a useful skill to have, anyway). I did it myself several times on Windows. I highly recommend **[this tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler)** for further reading. It has been vastly improved since the time I used it to build my first cross-compiler, several years ago. Good luck.

Comment: I don't need a CC, I already use Linaro CCs which works absolute excellent and are very up to date. And yes, I just copied the *.so libs from TARGET to Windows, I compiled and linked with Linaro CC and binary run back on TARGET like a charm :) Just perfect... All this because the Qt libraries are just impossible to be cross compiled on Windows for ARM... the free src is buggy and incomplete, perhaps that's why they have a commercial version. Anyhow, thanks very much for attention.